# Attendance System MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access-2010, time-and-attendance

I have 2 tables :

1. `StudentInfo`
2. `Attendance`

The `StudentInfo` table has fields about students like: `RollNo`, `FirstName`, `LastName` etc...

The `Attendance` table has the fields: `RollNo`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `InClass`(Yes/No) and `Date`.

I want to duplicate the common fields from `StudentInfo` to `Attendance` and when I add a new entry in the `StudentInfo` table it will automatically add them to the `Attendance` table.

Also, when I add attendances in the `Attendance` table then I want to be able to view the data by months or dates, so that I can see on what day how many students attend the class.

Can you suggest a way for me to store attendance of students like we store on register, your help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're putting the same values in two tables? The beauty of a relational design is being able to store data only once.

Comment: Spend 2 hours searching/reading about `Relation database design`. It wil give you a 500% return for sure.

Comment: To repeat what @AndrewBreza and @PatrickHonorez have said: You don't need to store duplicate student info (first name and last name) in your `Attendance` table. As long as it's in your `StudentInfo` table, you can obtain the student's name for a class by using a `JOIN`.

Comment: forget about the other fields but i really need to put the RollNo filed on both tables so that i can create a relation between them to use query and when i enter rollno on student info table it will also auto add on Attendance table. so is there any suggestion plz i am new to ms access , your help is really mean to me.

Comment: @Zack i am new to ms access , how does JOIN command work ? can u give some explanation to it ??

Comment: A join - as the command implies - joins two tables together.  This generally happens based on a key field shared between the two tables - such as `RollNo`.  If you join `StudentInfo` and `Attendance` on the `RollNo` field then `Attendance` doesn't need the student name - it will look it up off the `StudentInfo` table on demand.  Then, if _StudentA_ changes their name you only have to change it in one place and not for every day they've attended.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank u so muchh dareen , i need to know where this JOIN command work? on expression builder ? or can u give me example of this JOIN Command plzz

Comment: Visually you can see a join when you build a query - it's the line joining two tables.  As text a join is in the `FROM` clause of the SQL and will look something like `SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.PrimaryKey = TableB.ForeignKey`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank u so muchh i will try this :)

Comment: Read [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-simple-select-query-de8b1c8d-14e9-4b25-8e22-70888d54de59#bm3_2) for information about using JOINs in Access.

Comment: Good luck - I should point out that asking how a `JOIN` command works is similar to asking how a car works and someone saying "put your foot on the accelerator" - there's so much more than _just_ joining tables.